# How to pre load database in core data using swift 3 xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have a database with data and I want to preload that in application. Before swift 3 it works and I have followed this tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/ But how to load same database for swift 3? As `NSPersistentContainer` is introduced how can I load .sqlite file which is in my project?

Comment: Did find any solution ?

Comment: @LokeshChowdary yes.check I have added my answer and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually the default path where database was created is changed in swift 3 . So now the code   will look like :

```
func preloadDBData() {
    let sqlitePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyDB", ofType: "sqlite")
    let sqlitePath_shm = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyDB", ofType: "sqlite-shm")
    let sqlitePath_wal = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyDB", ofType: "sqlite-wal")

    let URL1 = URL(fileURLWithPath: sqlitePath!)
    let URL2 = URL(fileURLWithPath: sqlitePath_shm!)
    let URL3 = URL(fileURLWithPath: sqlitePath_wal!)
    let URL4 = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL().relativePath + "/MyDB.sqlite")
    let URL5 = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL().relativePath + "/MyDB.sqlite-shm")
    let URL6 = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL().relativePath + "/MyDB.sqlite-wal")

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL().relativePath + "/MyDB.sqlite") {
        // Copy 3 files
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: URL1, to: URL4)
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: URL2, to: URL5)
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: URL3, to: URL6)

            print("=======================")
            print("FILES COPIED")
            print("=======================")

        } catch {
            print("=======================")
            print("ERROR IN COPY OPERATION")
            print("=======================")
        }
    } else {
        print("=======================")
        print("FILES EXIST")
        print("=======================")
    }
}
```

Now you can call this method from AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchWithOptions` method and this will preload database which we have put in application.

Comment: Pooja: Have you done above code for iOS 9.0 support ?

Comment: @pooja Shah Have you done above code for ios 9.0 ? If so please help me.

Comment: @LokeshChowdary , Pooja: Have you worked with csv in the same project(https://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/)? I need to fetch data from csv and shown in table view.

Comment: @pkc456 You can directly convert csv file to db using tool name: sqlite or mesa sql then use that DB in app.

Comment: @PoojaShah : hey my app is crashed because in my application bundle I don't have all 3 files, Where from I extract 3 files. actually I follow the  http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/  tutorial and print the document path but not found any single file there.. Please help me out,
thanks in advance..!