# Alternative to loading large text file - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, load

I am attempting to make a word game for iOS where I need to check words against a dictionary to determine if the word is valid.

Currently I am loading the dictionary from a text file and storing it in a set.  However it takes a few seconds to load every time I start the app. The text file has approximately 250K lines.

Can I have the data available in an array or set without having to read a text file each time the app starts?

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: You can store them in database or something, without parsing and keeping them in the memory all the time.

Comment: Checking [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278194/how-to-make-offline-database-for-my-app/40278645#40278645) -hopefully- should be useful to your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider persisting your word file using, for example, Core Data.

On the first load of your app, you can populate your Core Data store (maybe in the background while the rules are being explained to the user).

Once this has been done you can query your words store using an `NSFetchRequest`

To use a pre-populated Core Data database you could start by populating in development…

```
let count = try! moc.count(for: request)
if count = 0 {
    loadWords()
}

func loadWords() {
    // run through your words.txt file and create object(s)
    // for each word
}
```

Once you're ready to release, add your database files into the app's resources, then add amend your `loadWords()` func to copy these files from the app bundle to the Core Data store's url

Comment: If I use Core Data, could I preload it with data instead of populating it on the first app load?

Comment: Copy files from bundle to Core Data url as shown here?  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761140/how-to-pre-load-database-in-core-data-using-swift-3-xcode-8)

Comment: Will mark this as correct answer but now have issue converting fetched Core Data results to a Set. See my new question.